# Configuration Error after login?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am trying to run my ASP.net application on my localhost machine and I am able to get to the first screen. (keep in mind that I am running this outside of VS2013) I go to my localhost/dsp and my login page appears. But once I login the following error message appears.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unable to open configSource file 'Connections.config'.

Source Error: 


Line 10:   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
Line 11:   
Line 12:   <connectionStrings configSource="Connections.config" />
Line 13: 
Line 14:   <appSettings>

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 12 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

I KNOW this is computer specific because it worked on my co-workers computer - but it will not work on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your web.config file and you will see it is pointing to a connections.config as a separate file. Look for that file and I bet you find it missing. Check your co-workers computer and you will find it is there. If so, problem is essentially solved.

If this is a project multiple developers are working on, the connections.config is most likely NOT in source control. Rectify that, check out, and the problem goes away. If not in source control, you are missing that file when you sneaker-netted the code.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and the file is there and it has information in it. I even copied the file from my co-workers computer and replaced mine. Everything seems to be lining up, but It's still not working.

Just to be clear, I go into Web.config in my project and it says
`<connectionStrings configSource="Connections.config" />`

Connections.config is located in the same project directory and has database information in it. Still no luck.

Comment: First, you compare content of the connections file, as it cannot be opened. Double check line 12 of the config file (count down from top). As a side option, make sure you have the database access needed. The next step in troubleshooting is to compare your machines. Source is the first step. The easiest way, from command prompt is navigate to the root directory and run "dir /b /s >c:\temp\appDirectory.txt". You can then compare the files with his files and see if anything is missing.